# strictNullChecks iterables in typescript

Tags: typescript

Having following possible issue with strictNullChecks in TypeScript (v. 3.2.1):

```
interface IData {
    data?: { payload: string };
}
const list: IData[] = [];
const index: number = 0;

//test a
if (list[index].data)
    list[index].data.payload = "a";

//test b
const item = list[index].data;
if (item)
    item.payload = "a";
```

Why does "test a" leads to a warning "object is possibly undefined"
and "test b" not? 
I there a good reason for the behavior?

http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20IData%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20data%3A%20%7B%20payload%3A%20string%20%7D%20%7C%20undefined%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aconst%20list%3A%20IData%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0D%0Aconst%20index%3A%20number%20%3D%200%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2Ftest%20a%0D%0Aif%20(list%5Bindex%5D.data)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20list%5Bindex%5D.data.payload%20%3D%20%22a%22%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2Ftest%20b%0D%0Aconst%20item%20%3D%20list%5Bindex%5D.data%3B%0D%0Aif%20(item)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20item.payload%20%3D%20%22a%22%3B

Answer (score 0):

The "closest comparable" key difference would be between:

```
if (list[0].data)
    list[0].data.payload = "a"; // OK
```

... and ...

```
if (list[index].data)
    list[index].data.payload = "a"; // Possibly NULL!
```

The answer to the question why is one different to the other is really the amount of analysis you need to perform to get to the answer during compilation. There is an interesting post on GitHub about the [trade-offs in control flow analysis](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998) that helps to explain this.

In your case, the use of the variable for the `index` currently prevents the type guard from sticking. Your solution of an intermediate variable is a pretty pragmatic fix.

```
const item = list[index].data;
if (item)
    item.payload = "a";
```